# Adding spring security to Zuul service in spring boot micro service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, netflix-zuul

I am new to micro service architecture.
We have few services like zuul service (api gateway), security service (connect to db check access) and xyz service.

I would like to know, how we can add spring security to the routes defined in the zuul service. ?

On defining authorizeRequests like below on zuul service, it should call security service internally and authenticate the requests.

Example:

```
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/user/count").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
```

Note: /user End point is defined in the security service.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Our Zuul proxy is supporting OAuth2 security.  An example of the security config is this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class JwtSecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
   public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_API_ACCESS")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
   }
}
```

I would assume if you are doing basic auth you could do something similar using the appropriate class.  Maybe something like this.

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint = new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();

authenticationEntryPoint
   .setRealmName("EnterpriseDeviceAuthentication");
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/health").permitAll() // allow access to health page
            .antMatchers("/somepath").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/somepath2").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/bootstrap.min.css").permitAll() 
            .anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority(SecurityRoles.ALL_SECURITY_ROLES)
            .and().httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }

}
```